# function getLargestElement - How to get this working with an array full of neg numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Working on the following practice problem:

> Write a function called `getLargestElement`.
>   Given an array, `getLargestElement` returns the largest number in the given array.
>   Notes:
>
> - It should return 0 if the array is empty.

The following is what I have coded and it works for an array of positive numbers, but when it's full of negative numbers, `0` is returned. And I understand why this is happening (setting `largest = 0` as well as the if statement `arr[i] > largest`) but I can't seem to think of another way to attack this.

Any hints? Thanks.

```
function getLargestElement(arr) {
  var largest = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    if (arr[i] > largest) {
      largest = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return largest;
}


var newList = [-5, -2, -8, -3];

getLargestElement(newList);
```

Comment: Don't assume that the largest is `0` but assume that the largest is the first item (`var largest = arr[0];`) and start looping from `1` up (`for(var i = 1; ...)`)!

Comment: Oh for sure, I got you! I'm new to using stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `largest = 0`, set it to the first element of the array. Then you can start your loop at `i = 1`, since you don't need to test `arr[0]`.

```js
function getLargestElement(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  var largest = arr[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    if (arr[i] > largest) {
      largest = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return largest;
}


var newList = [-5, -2, -8, -3];

console.log(getLargestElement(newList));
```

Comment: Just add `return largest || 0;`.

Comment: If the array is empty, `arr[0]` is undefined, and this will be returned. It's as good as anything else.

Comment: @Kinduser Why should it return `0` for an empty array? There's no largest element, so I return `undefined`.

Comment: Oops, I just saw that in the problem spec.

Comment: Dunno why did you add it this way.

Comment: @Kinduser It seems simpler to just check the length rather than access nonexistent elements unnecessarily.

Comment: @Kinduser I agree with barmar as the user is clearly a beginner so the OR operator is a littile bit too much to take at first! And it's better because then you'll skip the whole thing if the array is empty!

Comment: Thanks everyone! Makes perfect sense.

Comment: returns `NaN` for `[NaN, 0]` and `0` for `[0, NaN]`

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. 1) Set largest to arr[0] and start your loop from 1, that way you are only comparing the existing elements:

```
function getLargestElement(arr) {
  // filter out NaN and non numeric values
  arr = arr.filter(function(i) { return Number(i) === i });
  if (arr.length === 0) {
     return 0;
  }
  var largest = arr[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i ++) {
    if (arr[i] > largest) {
      largest = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return largest;
}


var newList = [-5, -2, -8, -3];

getLargestElement(newList);
```

Or 2, just use `Math.max` to determine the largest:

```
function getLargestElement(arr) {
    if (arr.length) {
       return Math.max.apply(null, arr.filter(function(i) { 
           return Number(i) === i;
       });
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or even easier in ES6:

```
const getLargestElement = (arr) => arr.length 
     ? Math.max(...arr.filter(i => Number(i) === i)) 
     : 0;
```

Comment: Using `Math.max()` seems like cheating on an obvious homework problem where you're supposed to implement the algorithm yourself.

Comment: @Barmar That's why I provided option 1 (which turns out to be the same solution you offered :P). I see what you mean, though I'm not sure that it is necessarily "cheating"; `Math.max` is a native language feature and it wasn't explicitly stated in the question that they can't use language features. What if they are being tested on knowledge of language features rather than algorithms? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: OK, but your `Math.max()` versions need to check for an empty array, because it returns `-Infinity` instead of `0` as in the problem statement.

Comment: Agreed, will amend my answer

Comment: your first version returns `NaN` for `[NaN, 0]` and `0` for `[0, NaN]` - `Math.max` returns `NaN` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `0` for empty arrays is a pretty esoteric choice, thus I prefer to intercept and handle this case explicitly before continuing with the main function body.

Then you need to initialize `largest = -Infinity` as no value is lower.

Also, when encountering a `NaN`, we break and return `NaN` to stay compliant with the standard set by `Math.max()`:

```js
function getLargestElement(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) return 0;
  
  // Identical to Math.max:
  var largest = -Infinity;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] > largest) {
      largest = arr[i];
    } else if (isNaN(arr[i])) {
      largest = NaN;
      break;
    }
  };
  return largest;
}

console.log(getLargestElement([-5, -2, -8, -3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of do this job could be;

```js
function getLargetElement(a){
  return a.length ? a.reduce((p,c) => p > c ? p : c) : 0;
}

var newList = [-5, -2, -8, -3],
     result = getLargetElement(newList);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `reduce` is a bit overkill for this!