# Function should return `0` when no numbers exist in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of mixed elements, my function needs to return the smallest number within that array.

**Requirements:**

- If the given array is empty, it should return 0.
- If the array contains no numbers, it should return 0.

I am failing to pass the test where it should return 0 if an array contains no numbers. Here is my code:

```js
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
  // your code here
  if (arr.length === 0) return 0;

  var shortest = arr.filter(function(a, b) {
    return typeof a === 'number' && a - b;
  });

  return Math.min.apply(null, shortest);
}

var output = findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(['string', 'string']);
console.log(output); //=> Infinity (expected 0)
```

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846325/function-getlargestelement-how-to-get-this-working-with-an-array-full-of-neg-n/42846433 - just swap the < operator.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42846435/4543207) up

Comment: your `arr.filter` callback subtracts the element (a) from its index (b) - why?

Comment: @le_m cause I don't fully understand what I was doing. I was trying to solve it with reduce() first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the length after filtering

```js
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
  // your code here

  var shortest = arr.filter(function(a) {
    return !isNaN(a);
  });
  if (shortest.length === 0) return 0;
  return Math.min.apply(null, shortest);
}

console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(["foo", "bar", 1]));
console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(["foo", "bar"]));
console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(["foo", "bar", 1, 2, 3]));
console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(["foo", "bar", 4, 6, 7]));
```

Note that using `!isNaN()` will convert a number passed as a string ->

```
console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(["foo", "bar", "4"]) // 4
```

So keep your check

```
return typeof a === 'number'
```

if you want to make sure it's a number passed as a number only ->

```
console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(["foo", "bar", "4"]) // 0
```

Comment: that is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to `filter` doesn't take two arguments. You should be first filtering your array to get only elements of type `number`, and then using the ternary operator to return the minimum if that list is non-empty and zero otherwise:

```js
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(array) {

  array = array.filter(function (e) { return typeof e === 'number' })

  return array.length ? Math.min.apply(null, array) : 0
}

console.log(
  findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(['10', 'the']) //=> 0
)

console.log(
  findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements([10, 'the']) //=> 10
)
```

Comment: Or just `return Math.min.apply(null, array) || 0`

Comment: I thought that would work too, but `Math.min.apply(null, [])` returns `Infinity`.

Answer (score -1):

This will return correct.

```
    function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
        var shortest = arr.filter(function (a, b) {
            return typeof a === 'number' ? 0 : a - b;
        });
        if (shortest.length === 0) return 0;
        return Math.min.apply(null, shortest);
    }
```